# Is it feasible to use already written front-end javascript on the back-end with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in the process of learning my first back-end language and have decided to use Javascript (node.js) since I already have a solid understanding of javascript on the front-end. I have a project in mind for a simple web-app that takes inputs from a user and then does some calculations, and spits out an output.

I actually have already written the logic in javascript on the front-end, so the app already works (albeit just on the front-end). Obviously to learn node and make an actual web-app I need to use the back-end to talk with the database, validation, etc

My question is, will I have to rewrite all the logic I already wrote (since I want it to be executed on the server - not the browser), or will I be able to use that same JS on the back-end? I'm in the process of learning JS on the FE vs BE so I apologize if this question has an obvious answer. Thanks so much

Comment: javascript is javascript. if it's only number calculations node.js is able to compile it just fine. problems occur if you mixed DOM manipulations into the code.

Comment: E.g. lodash works well in node.js. E.g. jquery, lacking DOM in node.js, doesn't. Is "depends" a valid answer to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Many frameworks like ReactJS and Meteor are based upon this basic premise of being able to share the same JS code on both client and server.  You just need to get familiar with making your code modular (ie using things like `require` or ES6 `import`) so that you can easily isolate the sections of code that are server-specific or client-specific.